# VS2010 Linker Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, header-files, linker-errors

**Solved** My "WorkoutGeneratorMain.cpp" was classified as a C++ header by the IDE. I'm not sure why that happened, but I fixed it. Now I get to deal with all of my other bugs.

Thanks all!

===================================================

I get the following error when compiling my program in Visual Studio 2010 Professional:

> ------ Build started: Project: WorkoutGenerator, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   Build started 8/15/2012 12:19:18 PM.
>   InitializeBuildStatus:
>      Touching "Debug\WorkoutGenerator.unsuccessfulbuild".
>   ClCompile:
>      LiftClass.cpp
>   ManifestResourceCompile:
>      All outputs are up-to-date.
>   MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol *main referenced in unction _*_tmainCRTStartup
>   C:\Users\Shanalex\Documents\Programming\C++Programming\WorkoutGenerator\WorkoutGenerator\Debug\WorkoutGenerator.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

In my searching, I have found several guides to fixing this; however, they almost all suggest that the file is a windows application set to console settings or vice versa. My program is a console application, and all settings appear to be correct for a win32 console application. Some where there is a linking error, but I don't seem to have any of the problems with my project settings that others have.

I am fairly new to multipart programs in C++ and VS2010. I could very easily be making an elementary mistake, but I haven't been able to find it when comparing my code to that of various tutorials and books.

I have three code files, as follows:

LiftClass.h

```
//Lift Classes
//Defines the Lift Class


#ifndef LIFTCLASSHEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define LIFTCLASSHEADER_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

class Lift
{
public:
    string LName;
    string LType;
    string LBody;
    vector<double> LLoadScale;

    Lift(string Name, string Type, string Body, 
        double Pawn, double Bishop, double Knight, double Rook, double Royal);
};

Lift::Lift(string Name, string Type, string Body, 
    double Pawn, double Bishop, double Knight, double Rook, double Royal)
{
    LName = Name,

    LType = Type,

    LBody = Body,

    LLoadScale.push_back(Pawn),
    LLoadScale.push_back(Bishop),
    LLoadScale.push_back(Knight),
    LLoadScale.push_back(Rook),
    LLoadScale.push_back(Royal);
}


#endif
```

Then, I have my .cpp implementation of the lift class, and a function for randomizing them.

LiftClass.cpp

```
//Exercise Randomizer using Lift Class
//Initializes Lifts for use in Workout Generator
//Version 2.0 will reference Database

#include "LiftClass.h"

Lift exerciseRandomizer() //Define database of exercise & randomly select one
{    
    vector<Lift> LiftDatabase;

    Lift Clean("Clean", "Olympic", "Full", .33, .66, 1, 1.33, 1.66);
    Lift Bench("Bench Press", "Heavy", "Upper", .33, .66, 1, 1.5, 2);

    LiftDatabase.push_back(Clean);
    LiftDatabase.push_back(Bench);

    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0))); //Seed random number

    unsigned randomNumber = rand(); //Generate Random Number

    //Get random between 1 and total lift count
    unsigned randomSelector = (randomNumber % LiftDatabase.size()); 

    return LiftDatabase[randomSelector];
}
```

And finally, I have my main function WorkoutGeneratorMain.cpp

WorkoutGeneratorMain.cpp

```
//Workout Generator
//Generates workouts based on goal and fitness level

#include "LiftClass.h"


int main()
{
    exerciseRandomizer();

    Lift LiftA = exerciseRandomizer();

    cout << "\n\nYour first lift is: " << LiftA.LName << "\n\n Its lift type is: " << LiftA.LType << endl;
    cout << "\n\nGood Luck!" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

-Alex

Comment: Off-topic but you should avoid `using namespace std;`, specially in header files.

Comment: I see `LiftClass.cpp` gets compiled: `ClCompile: LiftClass.cpp`. But I do not see same message for `WorkoutGeneratorMain.cpp`. Are you sure, it is included in your project?

Comment: You can get this error if you are linking with components that aren't using the same runtime.  Like single-thread/multi-threaded, debug/release, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You'd think that `int main()` is the entry point of the executable, but it's not (necessarily). :) Depending on project settings, the runtime might call `wmain` or `main`. Which is why you use `_tmain` instead, which is a macro expanding to what the runtime expects.

Try changing it to:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
```

PS - this should have been generated automatically, perhaps you deleted it instead of replacing the contents of `_tmain`.

Comment: The compiler should deal with that for you, based on the runtime you have selected.  If it's not, the project likely doesn't have the right runtime for the libraries it's linking with...

Comment: `int main()` shouldn't cause any problems.  `_tmain` allows Unicode applications to receive the command line arguments as Unicode strings, but it isn't _required_ to use `_tmain`.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis it will if it's a genereated project and the IDE already puts an `int main()` somewhere else, attempting to call a different version which it can't find.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore:  If you have a `_tmain`, there's not going to be a `main` somewhere else (unless you, the user, put one there).  `_tmain` is a macro that expands to either `main` or `wmain`.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis you're right, I had the wrong impression of what MSVS does in the background. Is this correct now?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore No, I mean runtime.  C entry-point is "main", the VC runtime supports that by mapping some other main (_tmain, WinMain, etc.).  If some sort of *main* can't be found, that's usually an indication that there's multiple, incompatible, runtimes in play.

Comment: It's correcter, but it doesn't answer the question.  Ideally, beginners should not concern themselves with compiler-specific details, especially ugly ones like TCHARs.  `int main()` will work just fine and is portable, and thus preferable where it is possible to use it.